# "Safe Drive Save Life"?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

"Safe Drive Save Life" is the name of a program initiated by the Government of West Bengal, a state in East India. You could look it up [here](http://www.uniindia.com/safe-drive-save-life-programme-reduces-accidents-in-bengal/states/news/1324076.html) and [here](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/kolkata/bengal-cm-makes-safe-drive-stickers-mandatory-for-vehicles/articleshow/65040452.cms).

[image: Safe drive save life]

Every time I go to the capital of West Bengal, Kolkata, I can't help but notice this expression on bumper stickers and billboards. **What bothers me is that it does not sound right.**

Is the expression "Safe Drive Save Life" correct? Is it missing any punctuation? Why does it sound so incorrect? Or is it just me?

Comment: Slogans don't need to meet grammar standards, they need to be punchy and memorable.

Comment: @KillingTime I'm with you on this. Not everything has to be grammatical. Especially in creative works like music and ads, it's okay to sacrifice grammar if doing so makes the writing better.

Comment: It is just that 'by Safe Drive; you Save Life. While there could be many, it is not that bad too.

Comment: @Ram Pillai Should this be tagged 'Indian English'? It sounds less than wonderful to my UK ears.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I think you can. This is an ad matter used by West Bengal, an Indian state. You can find hundreds of examples like this from India where, of late, untrained trainers train the youth saying "language means just convey the message".  Most new-gen teachers I have met have poor knowledge of grammar, syntax or the aesthetics of language.

Comment: @RamPillai I cannot deny that. Sometimes "Indian English" goes too far south. It's unhealthy. I don't know why it needs to be accepted internationally as an allowed form of English. Although I'm Indian, I'd rather have people correct their English to American or British standards. We don't have the right to play with a language that isn't our own.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer, I tend to agree and disagree with you. Even in the US and the UK, there are people with different levels of language knowledge; it is also possible that in countries where English is a 2nd or 3rd language, people's (at least some of them) knowledge of English is very good. For one who loves a English language, it's close to one's heart, perhaps more than their mother tongue. Your ref to American or British standards will take one to a variety of related matters. I fully agree with you that people (Indians as we know) compromise a lot on language quality.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Agree with you :)

Comment: So (1) It falls quite a way below formal 'BrE' standards of grammar. (2) I am fairly sure that the same is true as regards 'AmE'. (3) However, as @KillingTime says, 'Slogans don't need to meet grammar standards – they need to be punchy and memorable.' I agree with this, but within rather hard-to-define limits. (4) 'DRIVE SAFE – SAVE LIFE' is equally punchy and has equally obvious clever and pleasing near-'symmetry', and is less maladroit to my (British) ears. The flat-adverb-for-punchiness usage is well established nowadays. [sorry, @Ram; I'd better make it grammatical and correctly spaced]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the advertising industry

(including the so-called social advertising)

they sometimes invent slogans which are grammatically incorrect 
because the 
 [slogan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slogan) is a specific text ("a brief attention-getting phrase used in advertising or promotion").
(Sometimes the grammatical incorrectness can be explained by poor English.)

The slogan in question is a typical example of "[headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese?wprov=sfla1)  or [journalese](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/journalese) style".

There are some common characteristics:

1. Using the infinitive instead of the finite form (***save*** instead of ***saves***).
2. Pseudo [rhyming](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhyming) (***driVE*** - ***liFE***).
3. [Alliteration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alliteration) (***SAve*** - ***SAfe***).

Answer (score 0):

> *What bothers me is that it does not sound right.*

You are correct–it doesn't–and it is not "just you".

The idea is that the change in places of the 'F' and the 'V' in the top and bottom lines creates the slogan's memorability... or should do.

sa**F**e dri**V**e

sa**V**e li**F**e

It's a clever trick but it only half-works. Nobody notices the trick as they are stumbling over what exactly is it supposed to say.

Comment: 'Nobody notices the trick as they are stumbling over what exactly is it supposed to say.' You have experience of Indian English?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Yes, 40 years worth. (Actually, it is Bengali/Bangla.)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth The Bangla script says "Drive carefully, save lives", which is far better...

Comment: No; we don't deal with the source language here. 'Indian English' is the poor (as if there was no variation) umbrella term for the English used by many. / The one that is better is the one that saves more lives, not the one that prescriptivists prefer.